# Grouping by several fields and calculate difference between values

Tags: python, pandas

I' ve the following dataframe:

[image]

I've two seller_id for each item title for each number of week. What I'd like to do is to calculate the price difference between these two sellers (seller_id 221591137 - seller_id 143125485) on each product (title) on each week. So a desired response would be (for the first product):

```
week: 5, title: 'Anafe Orbis 724aco 4 H', diff_price: 0
week: 6, title: 'Anafe Orbis 724aco 4 H', diff_price: 300 (9799-9499)
```

I've tried several things but I can't get to a working solution.

Edit: [Link](https://pastebin.com/fCtR6Rs8) to sample data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [pandas.DataFrame.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to get the desired data as groups. You can then apply a function to this group, e.g.:

```
group = df.groupby(["title", "week"])
price_diff = group.apply(lambda x: x['price'].diff().iloc[0]
```

This will return a pandas.Series containing all the price differences.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I added a link to the sample data in csv format.